# Does Accelerometer Sensor work on my Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sensors, auto-rotation

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 and i'm experiencing with an issue that is annoying me very much.

When I do \auto rotate\ , the rotation happens after 4-5 seconds.

I've done the calibrations and all that stuff that you will find on google or forums.

After i checked secret code `*#0*#` , i noticed that: at Accelerometer Sensor I get:

> ACC Raw Data - X: changing numbers, y: changing numbers, z: 1024

( z is not changing like X and Y)

After this test i noticed  that somthing is wrong with this phone, and i doubt that the problem is with the sensor.

The strange thing is that sometimes my phone and accelerometer WORKS JUST FINE, but most of times it doesn't work at all!

So, does my phone have problem with sensor or something wrong with the software?

Here you can see in the graphic Accelerometer values
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvUzb.png

Please Help Me!!!

Comment: Not a programming question. This is not the right place.

Comment: Yeah, except it **is** a programming problem, because he's developing an app and the output he's getting from his code isn't jiving with what is expected.

Comment: Al Everett - you think that this is a problem with programming, not with sensor chip or whatever?!

Comment: It may very well be a problem with the sensor, but my point was that it should not have automatically been moved to here.

Answer (score 2):

Having an SGS2 myself, I just checked `*#0*#` and all 3 axis values change. So you definitely seem to have a problem here, either in software or hardware, and since you've already tried to search for solutions online and could not find anything which works, perhaps it's best to contact Samsung directly for help.

Comment: It's very very weird... today the accelerometer is working perfect. I didn't do nothing?! all 3 axis values change now.

After this, yet i really don't know what is the problem on phone. Is it sensor or software issue!!!!

Comment: After i did the calibration of the compass (this app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.apksoftware.compass) the accelerometer is not working.  
Again, cheking *#0*# at Accelerometer Sensor I get:

ACC Raw Data - X: changing numbers, y: changing numbers, z: 1024
( z is not changing like X and Y)